# Set and get value from noUiSlider in update panel using asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, updatepanel, nouislider

I'm using `noUiSlider` in `Asp.net webform` to set and get some number range.
This is my `aspx` code to create and initialize `uiSlider` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>UiSlider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="User/css/assets/vendor_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="User/css/assets/vendor_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-extend.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="User/css/master_style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="User/css/skins/_all-skins.css">
    <link href="Content/css/RezaModal.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/css/RezaStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.sweet-alert.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/custom.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/fontawesome-5.12.0-web/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/wNumb.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/nouislider.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #input-select,
        #input-number {
            padding: 7px;
            margin: 15px 5px 5px;
            width: 70px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div id="range"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="box-body">
                                    <div class="contact-page-aside">
                                        <ul class="list-style-none">
                                            <li>
                                                <input type="number" min="-20" max="40" step="1" name="txt" id="input-number">
                                                <select id="input-select"></select>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button id="btn_Refresh" type="submit" runat="server" onserverclick="btn_ServerClick">send to server </button>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>

    <script src="User/css/assets/vendor_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="User/css/assets/vendor_components/popper/dist/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="User/css/assets/vendor_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var select = document.getElementById('input-select');

        // Append the option elements
        for (var i = -20; i <= 40; i++) {

            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = i;
            option.value = i;

            select.appendChild(option);
        }

        var html5Slider = document.getElementById('range');

        noUiSlider.create(html5Slider, {
            start: [10, 30],
            connect: true,
            range: {
                'min': -20,
                'max': 40
            }
        });

        var inputNumber = document.getElementById('input-number');

        html5Slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {

            var value = values[handle];

            if (handle) {
                inputNumber.value = value;
            } else {
                select.value = Math.round(value);
            }
        });

        select.addEventListener('change', function () {
            html5Slider.noUiSlider.set([this.value, null]);
        });

        inputNumber.addEventListener('change', function () {
            html5Slider.noUiSlider.set([null, this.value]);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

after page run, `UiSlider` created and now I want to get the value of `input` and `select`. but I have no chance because of the update panel and ajax reset all input values. so I can get those values on server side.
I trying to get values this way:

```
protected void btn_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string textError = Request.Form["txt"];
        Response.Write(textError);
    }
```

I try to simulate a simple project using only javascript and update panel. but the error is the same and I think update panel or ajax can't get the value after postback in this way and there must be some tricks that I don't know.
The error shows on chrome console as following:

> MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'PRM_ParserErrorDetails' of undefined at
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._parseDelta
>   (MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js:6) at
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._onFormSubmitCompleted
>   (MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js:6) at Array. (MicrosoftAjax.js:6)
>   at MicrosoftAjax.js:6 at Sys.Net.WebRequest.completed
>   (MicrosoftAjax.js:6) at XMLHttpRequest._onReadyStateChange
>   (MicrosoftAjax.js:6)

**The simulated project `aspx` code:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <input id="lblmaxNum" name="lblmaxNum" runat="server" />
            <button id="btn_Refresh" type="submit" runat="server" 
                onserverclick="btn_Refresh_ServerClick">Refresh</button>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <script>
        function test(val) {
            var lblmaxNum = document.getElementById('lblmaxNum');
            lblmaxNum.value = val;
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

**And the simulated project `aspx.cs` code is:**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btn_Refresh_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            string script = "test('11111');";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "hg", script, true);
            Response.Write(Request["lblmaxNum"]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at generated HTML code to see generated id of your input.

Comment: Also use standard ASP.NET server controls `<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="lblmaxNum" />`. It will allow you to just set  new value in async postback (`lblmaxNum.Text = "Some Value";`) without custom JS script.

Comment: The Id is the same as I use it and Also I replace the input with `asp:TextBox` but the result is the same. I updated my post to explaining the main project.